# Firebase as a message storing backend

Tags: firebase

I'm looking to build a mobile app that will be able to send messages to users based on their location. Is it possible to create a database on Firebase that stores a message/location and than have the data be queried if there are new messages near the users location?

Comment: That depends.
If you would have users grouped for example by cities like Madrid, Barcelona, Bilbao etc. it would be easy.
If you would like to propagate message let say to closes 100 users that might be problematic.

Comment: I agree with @lombausch here ... Firebase isn't well suited to that type of query, unless you can narrow it down in some very clever way. You'd probably have to use a different backend to deal with geospatial data. The messages themselves though, sure.

Comment: Did you look at GeoFire (https://geofire.firebaseapp.com/)? It stores information based on its geolocation and allows querying by proximity based on geohashes. So: yes, it is possible.